# Unable to browse in Eclipse tables for any schema in Informix

Tags: eclipse, informix

***EDIT: Although this question is still unanswered for 3.X versions of Eclipse, using 4.X versions (Juno) solves the problem.***

I can't browse tables for a given schema in Informix using Eclipse Data Source Explorer. The only tables I can browse is the catalog, the sys* ones in the Informix schema.

I'm using Eclipse v3.6 (Helios) with Data Tools Project plugin v1.9.2 for accessing an Informix 11.70 database.
The driver (v10.0) and the connection configuration seem to be right as I can ping and query properly using the SQL scrap book, creating and selecting tables. In fact the applications work perfectly once deployed, but I'm unable to use Eclipse features such as JPS tools.
The user has the proper access and is able to browse and operate anything from Server Studio.

I've searched Google for a few days and found some cases expriencing something alike (for instance it can happen in MySQL if you're missing the database in the URL), but found no proper answer.

Thanks in advance

P.S.: I have the same question open in DTP forum http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/874976/#msg_874976

P.S. II: I've created a test project that illustrates the problem. Notice the "Tables" node can't be expanded.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue will be 'How does Eclipse Helios with Data Tools Project' go looking for tables in an Informix database?

If it interrogates the Informix system catalog directly (`systables`, `syscolumns`, ...), there should not be an issue.  The fact that you can browse the system catalog tables is curious.  Maybe it is only showing you tables 'owned by `informix`' in the Informix jargon; that would be 'in the schema `informix`' in some other systems' jargon.  Look at the plugin options to see if you can change the schema name somehow, or have it look at all schemas simultaneously.

If it is looking for standard SQL 'Information Schema' tables, those are AWOL in Informix. You might be able to run `dbaccess yourdb $INFORMIXDIR/etc/xpg4_is.sql` and get enough of an archaic version of the Information Schema tables (from the XPG4 – X/Open Portability Guide version 4 – definition of the Information Schema) to be usable, but I'd not want to bet on it being adequate.

Comment: Everything you're saying is correct but still I can't find a solution to browse the tables in Data Source Explorer and I noticed I'm maybe not explaining the problem in the most correctly way: I'm going to edit a bit the question.

Comment: I don't know what the Eclipse plugin is looking for.  Neither, probably, do you.  I've never managed to get on with Eclipse (or any other IDE), so I can't really help you by running it.  I'm trying to help to the best of my limited ability given the huge gap in knowledge on my part w.r.t all things Eclipse.

Comment: Is really appreciated. I guess the main problem falls into some tricky configuration in Eclipse as the applications work properly once deployed and the database admins find no problems at all. But if we get these tools to work, it would help us a lot on developing models with JPA.